# Javascript add value to object based on another value within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array

```
data = [{time:100,id:1},
        {time:300,id:2},
        {time:150,id:3},
        {time:100,id:4}]
```

I want to add another field (status) to every object in this array based on the time value , this field should indicate true if (time < 200) and false if not.
so the new array should look like this :

```
data = [{time:100,id:1,status:true},
        {time:300,id:2,status:false},
        {time:150,id:3,status:true},
        {time:100,id:4,status:true}]
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, so can you post the attempt that you have made that got you the closest?

Comment: sounds like one needs to loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve that:

```js
const data = [{
    time: 100,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    time: 300,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    time: 150,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    time: 100,
    id: 4
  }
]

console.log(data.map(el => ({ ...el,
  status: el.time > 200
})));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()`. `return` a new object from callback which contain all the previous props and one new prop `stauts`

```js
const data = [{time:100,id:1},
        {time:300,id:2},
        {time:150,id:3},
        {time:100,id:4}]
        
const res = data.map(x => ({...x,status:x.time < 200}));
console.log(res)
```